# cakephp overviews

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I recently started working with CakePHP but there are a few things I don't understand...

What do I have to do to get an overview of a couple of functions/views on one page like 'www.example.com/profile'. I really need help with this I am stuck in thinking in regular procedural php.

Comment: Like multiple blocks that display data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you should follow the Blog tutorial on the CakePHP cook book : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog

It's a great example and walks you through all the main stuff.

CakePHP follows an MVC structure and maps the URLs to [controller](http://book.cakephp.org/view/955/Controllers)/actions (using [routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1541/Routes))

In your example `www.example.com/profile`, if you haven't changed the default routing, actually maps to the `index` method in your  `ProfileController`. This method uses the view in `/views/profiles/index.ctp` to display output.

First follow the tutorial and read up on the CookBook to figure out what all this means. It's very easy to learn and they have some good documentation. Also check out [code generation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake) in CakePHP. It helps you create your apps faster (if used properly).

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the manual about [Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration). Also be familiar with basic Apache knowledge like mod_rewrite.

Comment: All those are Codeigniter links, not CakePHP